# C mq_receive() with struct causes seg fault when trying to access

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, posix, message-queue

So I have two programs that connect to a message queue, and one sends a message in the form of a struct to the other. However, When I try to access the struct after recieving it, I get a segmentation fault.

I can't figure out what I need to do to get access to the struct after its sent.

Here's my code for the sender:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct {
  char path[2048];
  char shm_name[50];
  size_t shm_s;
  char sem_send_name[50];
    char sem_recv_name[50];
} cache_request;

static void showAttr(mqd_t fd)
{
    struct mq_attr attr;
    mq_getattr(fd, &attr);
    printf("maxmsg = %ld\n", attr.mq_maxmsg);
    printf("msgsize = %ld\n", attr.mq_msgsize);
    printf("curmsgs = %ld\n", attr.mq_curmsgs);
}

int main()
{
    mqd_t fd;
    int ret;

    struct mq_attr attr;
    int flags = O_RDWR | O_CREAT;
    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 3;
    attr.mq_msgsize = 2216;
    attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;
    fd = mq_open("/mq", flags,(S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH),&attr );
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("open failed %d\n", fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("open ok\n");
    sleep(1);
    showAttr(fd);
    cache_request* msg = (cache_request*)malloc(sizeof(cache_request));
    strcpy(msg->path,"ok\n");
    strcpy(msg->shm_name, "ex1\n");
    msg->shm_s = 250;
    strcpy(msg->sem_send_name," ex2");
    strcpy(msg->sem_recv_name, "ex3");
    printf("hmm %s\n", msg->shm_name);
    printf("hmm %ld\n", msg->shm_s);
    //res = mq_receive(fd, (char*) &msg, sizeof(cache_request), NULL);
    int res = mq_send(fd, (const char*) &msg, sizeof(cache_request), 0);
    if (res < 0) {
          printf ("   Error %d (%s) on server mq_send.\n",
              errno, strerror (errno));
          mq_close(fd);
          mq_unlink("/mq");
          exit (1);
      }
    sleep(10);
    ret = mq_close(fd);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("open failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("close ok\n");
    sleep(20);
    mq_unlink("/mq");
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the receiver:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mqueue.h> // for message queue
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/*
gcc [file] -lrt
*/

typedef struct {
  char path[2048];
  char shm_name[50];
  size_t shm_s;
  char sem_send_name[50];
    char sem_recv_name[50];
} cache_request;


static void showAttr(mqd_t fd)
{
    struct mq_attr attr;

    mq_getattr(fd, &attr);

    printf("maxmsg = %ld\n", attr.mq_maxmsg);
    printf("msgsize = %ld\n", attr.mq_msgsize);
    printf("curmsgs = %ld\n", attr.mq_curmsgs);

}

int main()
{
    mqd_t fd;
    int ret;




    mq_unlink("/mq");
    struct mq_attr attr;
    int flags = O_RDWR;
    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 3; // ***
    attr.mq_msgsize = 141;
    attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

    while((fd = mq_open("/mq", O_RDWR)) == -1){
      printf("Couldnt connect to message queue in cache\n");
      sleep(2);
    }

    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("open failed %d\n", fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("open ok\n");

    //sleep(5);

    showAttr(fd);
    char* rsp_msg = (char*)malloc(2216);
    int res = mq_receive(fd, (char*) &rsp_msg, 2216, NULL);
    printf("recieved: %d\n", res);
        printf("should be %ld\n", sizeof(cache_request));
    if (res < 0) {
          printf ("   Error %d (%s) on server mq_receive.\n",
              errno, strerror (errno));
          mq_close(fd);
          mq_unlink("/mq");
          exit (1);
      }
    cache_request* msg = (cache_request*)rsp_msg;
    printf("shm_s: %ld\n", msg->shm_s); //THIS is where the seg fault happens
        printf("shm_name: %s\n", msg->shm_name);
    ret = mq_close(fd);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("close failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("close ok\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: regarding: `cache_request* msg = (cache_request*)malloc(sizeof(cache_request));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.   2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call: `perror( "malloc failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `printf("open failed %d\n", fd);`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  2) when the error is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the error occurred to `stderr`.  The function: `perror()` properly handles both these actions

Comment: regarding: `while((fd = mq_open("/mq", O_RDWR)) == -1){
      printf("Couldnt connect to message queue in cache\n");
      sleep(2);`  1) error messages to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) if it failed once, it will continue to fail so better to call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` rather than looping

Comment: regarding: `int res = mq_receive(fd, (char*) &rsp_msg, 2216, NULL);`  This is passing the 'address of an address' for `rsp_msg`.  Strongly suggest removing the leading `&` from the `rsp_msg` parameter;  Note: `rsp_msg` is already a pointer.

Comment: regarding: `attr.mq_msgsize = 141;` and `int res = mq_receive(fd, (char*) &rsp_msg, 2216, NULL);`   The max message size is only 141 but the code is trying to pass a `2216` message size.  Suggest the max message size be (at least) `2216`

Comment: regarding: `printf("should be %ld\n", sizeof(cache_request));`  The operator: `sizeof` returns a `size_t` (I.E. long unsigned int) (which has a special output format conversion specifier)  so the output format conversion specifier should be: `%zu` not `%ld`

Comment: since the expression: `sizeof(cache_request))` is available, why is the 'magic' number 2216 used all over the code?

Comment: @user3629249 Excellent observations all around. changing &rsp_msg to msg is what did it for my original problem. Some of the strangeness is also a result of me pulling my hair trying to find out what was happening, such as the magic 2216. As for looping when mq_open returns -1, this is because it isn't  the one creating the message queue, so if this one is executed before the other, then it loops until the other process creates the queue

Comment: here is an excerpt from the MAN page for `mq_receive()`  *If the queue is empty, then, by default, mq_receive()  blocks  until  a
       message  becomes available, or the call is interrupted by a signal handler.  If the O_NONBLOCK flag is enabled for the message queue description, then the call instead fails immediately with the error EAGAIN.*  The posted code does not set the `NONBLOCK` attribute, so the call will 'hang' until some message is available.  I.E. no need for any looping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int res = mq_send(fd, (const char*) &msg, sizeof(cache_request), 0);
```

Should be `msg`, not `&msg`.  You want to send the data that `msg` points to, not the pointer itself.

```
int res = mq_receive(fd, (char*) &rsp_msg, 2216, NULL);
```

Likewise.

Also, better to use `sizeof(cache_request)` instead of hardcoding `2216`.